# Android: How to save a JSON file that let you keep the data even after power off?

Tags: android

Okay, so I have this file system using serializer to save an arraylist into a JSON file. The JSON file is created in the code. If I turn off the power, the data and file is erased. So if I want the data saved and reloaded even when the android phone is restarted. Which way to save data is the best? Can we use a JSON file to do that?

Comment: Files are not erased when devices are turned off.

Comment: Just save your JSON file on file system and reuse it when you need.

Comment: something is not right in your code. Like CommonsWare said, files are not erased! Anyway, why you save data into json if u have database for that?

Comment: Let me double check the code then. Anyone know how to find where the file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` or `saving it to external storage` or`saving it to SQLliteDB`

you can convert the `JSONObject` to a string and save by using one of the above methods.

for examples on using different storage options please refer [Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can save in a file into the `sdcard` or you can use the `SharedPreferences`. In fact the `toString()` of a `JSONObject` returns a String that represent the json itself